# Sahi Automated test text fields blank & File uploads don't work

Tags: internet-explorer-9, orbeon, sahi

I'm trialling Sahi for test automation. I'm trying to complete forms built with Orbeon forms. I'm using IE9 on Windows 7.

Basically I complete a form (that's got tabs and links to different stages required for submission). It also includes attaching a file or files.

Test's done with Firefox and Chrome work fine, with the exception that the file uploads, even though they don't generate an error, the files don't actually get uploaded.

Running the same test on IE9 generates script error.  So, I've created a specific test using IE9.  This runs without generating any error but all text input fields and dropdown fields end up blank when examined.  Also, files don't get uploaded.

Any idea as to what could be the problem?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Please check with Sahi Pro, it has up-to-date fixes for browser issues, including the one you report.

Regards,
Narayan

Comment: Hi;  I am indeed using Sahi Pro, but fields are still blank on Windows 7, IE9 and uploads still don't work. Oh, I should mention that it's a Windows 7 64 bit machine (and I would presume, the 64 bit version of IE9[??])

Comment: Yes it looks like a focusin/focusout related event was missing in IE9. A patch is on the way.